# Dockerfile: An appended variable is not persisted between RUN instructions

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have exported the variables to make sure that even in a new instance of the shell the variable is persisted but it doesn't work...
I don't know how I should do it.
I've done a lot of research and testing, nothing conclusive.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:stretch

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ARG VAR1="1"
ARG VAR2="Hello"

# Export arguments
RUN export VAR1="${VAR1}" \
    && export VAR2="${VAR2}"

# Output "Hello world"
RUN if [ $VAR1 = "1" ]; then VAR2+=" world"; fi \
    && echo $VAR2

# Output "Hello" instead of "Hello World"
RUN echo $VAR2
```

For sure each `RUN` happens in a new shell.

But why the heck `VAR2+=" world"` is not persisted since `export VAR2="${VAR2}` is persisted?

I really don't get it.

Thanks in advance to anyone who finds a way to tackle this odd behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile: Output of RUN instruction into a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213837/dockerfile-output-of-run-instruction-into-a-variable)

Comment: `RUN export ...` anything is always a no-op; that statement isn't persisted.  I think [you're getting the ARG value expanded](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#using-arg-variables) instead.

Comment: @DavidMaze No, it's not expanded, those are exported as `env vars` correctly. See my answer, `$VAR1` __is not__ expanded but used only from within `bash` script as I'm using single quotes instead of the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) you can either pass environment variable using either of `-e, --env, --env-file` or bash's `export` as you did above.

You cannot set the variable using `bash` script, try to `export` another variable (say `VAR3`) inside your if clause.

You can go with something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834331/set-environment-variables-in-docker), but it's really ugly:

```
FROM bitnami/minideb:stretch

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ARG VAR1="1"
ARG VAR2="Hello"

# Export arguments
RUN export VAR1="${VAR1}" \
    && export VAR2="${VAR2}"

RUN echo 'if [ $VAR1 = "1" ]; then VAR2+=" world"; fi' > ~/.bashrc

# Output "Hello" instead of "Hello World"
RUN source ~/.bashrc && echo "$VAR2"
```

You could make your script (`my_env` above) outside of the Docker file and source it from within, or use `-e, --env, --env-file`, the latter being much better.

Comment: I wonder if there's any way to do that in a `.bashrc` it would be cleaner...
Since `RUN` make a new instance of the shell everytime.

Comment: Just change the filename to `.bashrc`, that's all you would have to do. Not really cleaner in my opinion, but it's your choice. Edited my answer so it works with .bashrc

Answer (score -3):

You can try adding "export" :

```
RUN if [ $VAR1 = "1" ]; then export VAR2+=" world"; fi \
    && echo $VAR2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please verify your answer as it does not work. You should test it before posting.