# No such file or directory when executing command via docker run -it

Tags: bash, docker, ebcli

I have this Dockerfile (steps based on installation guide from [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-linux.html))

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest

RUN yum install python37 -y

RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

RUN python3 get-pip.py --user

RUN pip3 install awsebcli --upgrade --user

RUN echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN source ~/.bashrc

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I build the image with `docker build -t eb-cli .` and then run `eb --version` inside container `docker run -it eb-cli`, everything works

```sh
bash-4.2# eb --version
EB CLI 3.20.3 (Python 3.7.1)
```

But, when I run the command directly as `docker run -it eb-cli eb --version`, it gives me this error

```
/bin/bash: eb: No such file or directory
```

I think that is problem with bash profiles, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sourced `.bashrc` would stay in the layer it was sourced, but won't apply to the resulting container. This is actually more thoroughly explained in this answer:

> Each command runs a separate sub-shell, so the environment variables are not preserved and `.bashrc` is not sourced

<sup>*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55213158/2123530*</sup>

A solution for you would be to set the `PATH` in an environment variable of the container, rather, and blank the `ENTRYPOINT` as set by your base image.

So you could end with an image as simple as:

```sh
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest

ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"

RUN yum install python37 -y \
    && pip3 install awsebcli

ENTRYPOINT []
```

With this *Dockerfile*, here is the resulting build and run:

```sh
$ docker build . -t eb-cli -q
sha256:49c376d98fc2b35cf121b43dbaa96caf9e775b0cd236c1b76932e25c60b231bc
$ docker run eb-cli eb --version
EB CLI 3.20.3 (Python 3.7.1)
```

*Notes*:

- you can install the really latest version of pip, as you did it, but it is not needed as it is already bundled in the package `python37`
- installing packages for the user, with the `--user` flag, is a good practice indeed, but since you are running this command as `root`, there is no real point in doing so, in the end
- having the `--upgrade` flag does not makes much more sense, here, as the package won't be installed beforehand. And upgrading the package would be as simple as rebuilding the image
- reducing the number of layer of an image by reducing the number of `RUN` in your *Dockerfile* is an advisable practice that you can find in the [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers)

Comment: What's the difference between `ENTRYPOINT [""]` and removing it altogether ?

Comment: @Philippe removing it won't work because the base image `amazon/aws-cli:latest` defines one [`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/aws"]`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/docker/Dockerfile#L21) and this will get in the way of the OP's command that should run on bash.